# SharePoint List Validation When Status is set and No Date

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have a list that I'm trying to write a validation for when a user selects a specific status in a column it verified that they have set the date in another column.

Here is what I have but it is throwing an error:

*=IF(AND([Scheduled Status]="Delivery Scheduled", ISBLANK([Scheduled Date])='Yes')*

Also trying to write the same type of validation for another column that could have multiple statuses:

*=IF(AND([Scheduled PickUp Status]="Store Pickup", ISBLANK([Scheduled Pickup Start Time Date])>Today() and ISBLANK([Scheduled Pickup End Time Date])>Today()
    AND([Scheduled PickUp Status]="Warehouse Pickup", ISBLANK([Scheduled Pickup Start Time Date])>Today())  and ISBLANK([Scheduled Pickup End Time Date])>Today())*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISBLANK should not accpet a boolean condition.

AND(CONDITION1,CONDITION2,CONDITION3)

Sample demo:

```
=IF([Scheduled PickUp Status]="Store Pickup",AND([Scheduled Pickup Start Time Date])>Today(),[Scheduled Pickup End Time Date])>Today()),IF([Scheduled PickUp Status]="Warehouse Pickup"),AND([Scheduled Pickup Start Time Date])>Today(),[Scheduled Pickup End Time Date])>Today()),TRUE)
```